# Show that $(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{1/p} \ge \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> **Question:** Show that $(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^{1/p} \ge \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ in which $p>1$, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$

Could you give me some hint to solve this problem. I see that it like the Minkovski's inequality but it not true. Thank all!

Comment: Google Power Means Inequality...

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily showed by Weighted Power Mean. $\;$ You can see Weighted Power Mean by here on page $2$ https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf